# How to "convert" setText to a listview in Android

Tags: android, listview, settext

I found sample code to show the battery stats. The only one "problem" with it is that I want to display this information in a `listview` and not with `setText`. This is the relevant part of the code:

```
private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     int  health= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH,0);
     int  icon_small= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_ICON_SMALL,0);
     int  level= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,0);
     int  plugged= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED,0);
     boolean  present= intent.getExtras().getBoolean(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PRESENT); 
     int  scale= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE,0);
     int  status= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS,0);
     String  technology= intent.getExtras().getString(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY);
     int  temperature= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0);
     int  voltage= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE,0);


     batteryInfo.setText(
             "Health: "+health+"\n"+
             "Icon Small:"+icon_small+"\n"+
             "Level: "+level+"\n"+
             "Plugged: "+plugged+"\n"+
             "Present: "+present+"\n"+
             "Scale: "+scale+"\n"+
             "Status: "+status+"\n"+
             "Technology: "+technology+"\n"+
             "Temperature: "+temperature+"\n"+
             "Voltage: "+voltage+"\n");
         imageBatteryState.setImageResource(icon_small);
  }
};
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: you need to use a custom listview with custom adapter for this purpose.

Comment: I'm pretty noob on android actually, can you post an example? even from my code if it's easyer

Comment: http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ListView` with [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)

**EDIT 1**

Create a `String` array like:

```
String[] status = {
                "Health: "+health,
                "Icon Small:"+icon_small,
                "Level: "+level,
                "Plugged: "+plugged,
                "Present: "+present,
                "Scale: "+scale,
                "Status: "+status,
                "Technology: "+technology,
                "Temperature: "+temperature,
                "Voltage: "+voltage
};
```

and pass this array in `setAdapter()`

`lvStatus.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, status));`

**EDIT 2**
You have to implement `ListView` in you layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_Status"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ListView>
```

Then, you have to reference it in your `Activity`

```
    ListView lvStatus = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_Status);
```

Comment: @user2508402 if you google search you find many examples of custom listview.

Comment: Krrishnaaaa link can be posted as a comment.

Comment: not very easy for me :(.. so i can't make directly and array right?like: `String[] funct = {+level+","+status+","+scale}; lista = {ListView} findViewById(R.id.batteryinfos); ArrayAdapter<String> arr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, funct); lista.setAdapter(arr);` ?

Comment: You can use `ArrayAdapter` https://github.com/krrishnaaaa/listviewdemo/ But, `BaseAdapter` could be useful if you need to modify the layout, or want to add additional details.

Comment: Thanks @Krrishnaaaa but the problem is that i can't :( seems impossible that to do a simple listview i have to create classes or other things. My method would be better..but doesn't work!

Comment: Really thanks, but i get an error: RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent.. Another one thing, with your code where the listview would be created?

Comment: edited my answer.. and for your `RunTimeException`.. please post `StackTrace` from `LogCat`

Comment: You are my hero!!! ahahah it works!!!!!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!i will pay a drink ahah :)

Comment: So in this way you posted it's not possible?

Comment: The thing is if you want to display a list then `ArrayAdapter` is best option to go with.. But, if you want to show a customized `ListView` then you have to override `BaseAdapter` and design a custom `Layout` for the purpose. You can watch a tutorial for using BaseAdapter http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5vtvMM58y8 GitHub link to the project https://github.com/krrishnaaaa/CustomListViewDemo

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a layout for each row, and to `TextView` in it.

Then you create a `List<Map<String, String> list = new ArrayList<>();` for holding the battery info like Key -> Value.

And at last, you need to create two arrays

```
String[] from = new String[] {<the keys>};
int[] to = new int[] {<the id\'s in your layout>};
```

And then just put it to an adapter:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
                                   R.layout.your_layout, from, to);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```